Help with proof in Gentzen-style Natural Deduction
For the life of me, I'm not able to show the following using Gentzen-style ND:
$\neg \forall x \exists y Pxy \vdash \exists x \forall y \neg Pxy$
We may use all the usual rules: $\land$-I, $\land$-E, $\lor$-I, $\lor$-E, $\to$-I, $\to$-E, $\neg$-I,$\neg$-E, CR (classical reductio), $\forall$-I, $\forall$-E, $\exists$-I, $\exists$-E, $=$-I, $=$-E. But we may not use any theorems or metatheorems.
I tried a bunch of stuff, but all my attempts fail at performing the all-introduction at the appropriate time. I'm not sure what to assume such that the constant appearing in the assumption doesn't hinder all-introduction (as the constant is not arbitrary should it appear in an open assumption).
For example, see the following (wrong) attempt:

The all-introduction is wrong because $b$ is not arbitrary.
But how else to proceed? Thanks for the help!

A possible approach is to assume Pxy and also $\lnot \exists y Pxy$. Then a first contra dischargin the first and deducing $\lnot Pxy$.

Now generalize in y and introduce the existential in x to have a second contra with the assumed negation of the formula to be proved. By DN discharge the other assumption above to get $\exists y Pxy$.

Now generalize again, no more assumption with x free left, and get the third and final contra.

Don't walk in front of a truck. :D Thank you, your solution was spot on. I just didn't think of assuming $\neg \exists y Pxy$. Can you elaborate on the thought process that got you there, or was this simply experience / talent?
Do you want to post your comment as a reply? If not, then I'll do that.

Experience, of course, but also reflecting on your attempt and trying to fix it.

The result is "classic": so your idea of using somewhere LEM or DN is sound.
A possible approach is to assume, in addition to the negation of the formula to be derived, $Pxy$ and $¬∃yPxy$ as well. Using $(\exists \text I)$ we have a first contradiction discharging the first formula and deducing $¬Pxy$.
Now we can generalize wrt $y$ and introduce the existential quantifier for $x$ to have a second contradition with the assumed negation of the formula to be proved. By DN we will discharge the second assumption above to get $∃yPxy$.
Now we can generalize again, because there are no more assumptions with $x$ free, and we get the third and final contradiction.

$\neg \forall x \exists y Pxy \vdash \exists x \forall y \neg Pxy$ requires a classical proof, so instead prove $\neg \forall x \exists y Pxy \vdash \neg \neg \exists x \forall y \neg Pxy$ and remove the double-negation.
I write Fitch-styled proofs, so you'll have to adapt this to your ND format, which didn't have a $DNE$ rule in it:
$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}\fitch{~~1.~~\neg \forall x~\exists y~Pxy\hspace{20ex}\rm P}{\fitch{~~2.~~\neg\exists x~\forall y~\neg Pxy\hspace{15ex}\rm SM\neg I}{\fitch{~~3.~~\boxed a\hspace{22.5ex}\rm SM\forall I}{\fitch{~~4.~~\neg\exists y~Pay\hspace{13ex}\rm SM\neg I}{\fitch{~~5.~~\boxed b\hspace{16ex}\rm SM\forall I}{\fitch{~~6.~~Pab\hspace{11ex}\rm SM\neg I}{~~7.~~\exists y~Pay\hspace{7.5ex}\rm \exists I,6\\~~8.~~\bot\hspace{13ex}\rm \neg E, 7,4}\\~~9.~~\neg Pab\hspace{13ex}\rm \neg I,6{-}8}\\10.~~\forall y~\neg Pay\hspace{13ex}\rm \forall I, 5{-}9\\11.~~\exists x\forall y~\neg Pxy\hspace{10ex}\rm \exists I,10\\12.~~\bot\hspace{20ex}\rm \neg E, 2,11}\\13.~~\neg\neg\exists y~Pay\hspace{15ex}\rm \neg I, 4{-}12\\14.~~\exists y~Pay\hspace{19ex}\rm DNE, 13}\\15.~~\forall x~\exists y~Pay\hspace{20ex}\rm \forall I~3{-}14\\16.~~\bot\hspace{27ex}\rm\neg E, 1,15}\\17.~~\neg\neg\exists x~\forall y~\neg Pxy\hspace{18ex}\rm\neg I,2{-}16\\18.~~\exists x~\forall y~\neg Pxy\hspace{22ex}\rm DNE,17}$
The trick involves some knowledge about classical vs. intuitionistic logic. In intuitionistic logic, unless you have a constant on which to apply $\exists I$, you can't prove an existential statement, and Gentzen's original rule set was for intuitionistic logic. Instead, you can only prove double-negations of them. Since $\neg \exists x \phi$ is intuitionistically equivalent to $\forall x \neg \phi$, that's the path to least resistance that also gives you to two arbitrary constants, which your attempted proof lacked.

Thanks, also super useful answer!

@ichbinviele It's a pretty common stumbling block. Happy I could help.

"which didn't have a DNE rule in it:"   Indeed, however, that is the role of classical reduction ($\rm CR$) which combines $\neg\mathrm I$ with $\rm DNE$.   Which is more often known as Indirect Proof.

@GrahamKemp , gotcha. That'll save OP a couple of lines in the above answer, then.
However, in the proof he gave below, it looks like $CR$ is for $EFQ$, since he doesn't have $\bot E$ and uses $\neg E$ for $\bot I$.

This question already has correct answers, but here the proof in Gentzen ND!
$$\dfrac{\hspace{-4ex}\dfrac{\dfrac{\dfrac{}{\quad Pab\quad}{1\hspace{-1.5ex}}}{\exists y~Pay}{\exists\mathrm I}\quad\dfrac{}{\neg\exists y~Pay}{2\hspace{-1.5ex}}}{\dfrac{\bot}{\dfrac{\neg Pab}{\dfrac{\forall y~\neg Pay}{\exists x~\forall y~\neg Pxy}{\exists\mathrm I\hspace{-2.5ex}}}{\forall\mathrm I, b\hspace{-5ex}}}{\neg\mathrm I, 1\hspace{-3ex}}}{\neg\mathrm E\hspace{-4ex}}\quad\lower{9.5ex}{\dfrac{}{\neg\exists x~\forall y~\neg Pxy}{3\hspace{-2ex}}}}{\dfrac{\dfrac{\bot}{\dfrac{\exists y~Pay}{\forall x~\exists y~Pxy}{\forall\mathrm I, a\hspace{-4.5ex}}}{\mathrm{CR}, 2}\quad\lower{5ex}{\neg\forall x~\exists y~Pxy}}{\dfrac{\bot}{\exists x~\forall y~\neg Pxy}{\mathrm{CR},3}}{\neg\mathrm E\hspace{-30ex}}}{\neg\mathrm E}$$
